# How can you turn Core Isolation Memory Integrity back off again in Windows 10 build 17127 and later

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-defender

In Windows 10 Insider Preview builds, in Windows Defender Security Center, after the Fall Creators Update, Windows Insiders will see a new feature Core Isolation.

It's possible to turn the Memory Integrity switch on in the GUI so that part is easy. It may be hard for some people to turn it back off again because the feature was not fully designed properly, or the feature is buggy or incomplete.

I get a message that these settings are controlled by my administrator. I'm the local admin, there is no domain admin, and my settings are not controlled by someone else.  Core Isolation prevents you from using third party virtualization technologies (like VMWare Player and Virtual Box).

There must be registry or group policy ways to disable this feature in Windows again. How is it done?

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed this impacting performance at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been wondering about this, too; fortunately, it seems that it's as easy as setting the following registry key to 0:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled